# Comparing logarithms with different bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, alternative-proof, number-comparison

$\log_3 4$ and $\log_7 10$: which of these two logarithms is greater?

I figured out that both are between $1$ and $2$, then between $1$ and $1.5$. And then $\log_34$ is greater than $1.25$, and $\log_710$ is smaller than $1.25$. However, that method doesn't work for every example, and I wonder if there's a easier way to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: I figured out that both are between 1 and 2, then between 1 and 1.5. And then $/log_3 4$ is greater than 1.25 and $/log_7 10$ is smaller than 1.25. Howewer that method doesn't work for every example and i wonder if there's a easier way to solve this?

Comment: On second thoughts, this is *not* a duplicate of the other question, because none of the answers given in that case, including my own, can be applied in this case! (Ditto [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948737).) It is interesting to ask if there is some general result that *can* be applied in this case; or at least, some other argument than the one given by the questioner himself (which I take it is essentially that $4^4 > 3^5$ and $10^4 < 7^5$, so $\log_34 > 5/4 > \log_710$). I suppose I should withdraw my close vote, if that's possible. Meanwhile, I've upvoted the question.

Comment: To reduce the likelihood of the question being closed, perhaps the questioner should incorporate the text of his comment, showing work done on the problem, into the question itself.

Comment: By a *really* strained application of a method used for the other question, one *could* argue that $\log_34 = \log_{27}64 > \log_{49}100 = \log_710$, because $64/27 > 2\tfrac{1}{3} > 100/49$ and $27 < 49$. But only a madman would do it that way! (Sorry, I mean only a mad *person* would do it that way.) :)

Comment: In [this Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29317/213690), and its comments, there is some discussion of the history of similar questions in MSE, and suggestions as to how the present question might be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof using no numbers larger than $128$. We have $81 < 125 < 128$, i.e. $3^4 < 5^3 < 2^7$, therefore $\log_35 > \tfrac{4}{3}$ and $\log_25 < \tfrac{7}{3}$, therefore $\log_25 < 1 + \log_35$, therefore:
$$
\log_210 < 2 + \log_35 = \log_345 < \log_349 = 2\log_37,
$$
therefore $\log_410 < \log_37$, therefore $\log_34 > \log_710$. $\square$

The last step uses the general proposition that $\log_ab > \log_cd$ if and only if
$\log_bd < \log_ac$, which can be proved by rewriting all the logarithms in terms of logarithms to a single base (e.g. $\log_ab = \ln b/\ln a$, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

We'll  show that $$\log_34>\log_710$$ or
$$4>3^{\log_710},$$ which is true because $$\log_710<1.2$$ and $$4>3^{1.2}.$$